# Trouble overriding layout file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm using Magento 2.02
I've created my own theme called 'cff', which is based on Luma.

I'm trying to remove the `catalog.compare.link` block in `top.links`

The layout for this block seems to be defined in

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

And if I add

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" />
```

in that file, then as expected the 'Compare Products' text disappears from the top.links block.

However, I know I'm not supposed to change vendor files. So I'm looking for the correct folder in which to create my own `default.xml` file to place the remove code:

I've looked everywhere in the documentation and online but cannot find this info. I've tried several locations, none of them work. I thought this one should work but it doesn't either:

```
/app/design/frontend/cff/cff/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml
```

Please can someone tell me where the override layout should go?

This is the code inside my overriding layout `default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: First of all pls upgrade to the latest version of Magento2 ( 2.1.5 ) and it should work normal. also if you are on development enviornment DON'T use static content deploy, that is for production, and on development you should use symlinks. Also don't forget to remove/refresh cache "php bin/magento cache:flush" in the root of your magento or from admin

Answer (score 1):

You could try just removing the compare reference container: `compare-link-wrapper`

```
<referenceContainer name="compare-link-wrapper" remove="true" />
```

There is a little documentation regarding removing elements via layout xml but you can find it here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

In regards to your question about where that file needs to live:
You are correct in your assumption that we need to extend the default.xml by extending it in our theme's `Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml` or `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

I just tried using the exact same code you provided and had no problems removing the compare block I would double check that you cleared your caches and don't need to publish anything to your pub directory.

**UPDATE 4/7/16:**

You can refresh your pub directory by manually deleting the `pub/static` directory and then running the command:

```
setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, I don't understand your first sentance. what is a 'compare reference container'? the code you give does not appear in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml. I have tried the file in both the locations you suggest but it does not work. Please can you think of a reason why that might be? And finally, what do you mean 'publish anything to your pub directory? Shouldn't magento take care of everything in that folder? Sorry to be dim, the learning curve is bloody steep round these parts...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say thanks for your answer Tyler! I really appreciate your help..

Comment: @jo  I added some

Answer (score 0):

In your theme folder go to **Magento_Theme/layout** folder first.

then create **layout/override/base** folder and add **default.xml file** from vendor and add `<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" />`.

Comment: no need to override , just update to latest version of Magento use the method he tryed already and maybe just remove cache

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing referenceContainer **sidebar.additional** from product listing page. I did the following procedures.

1. I just copied **`<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">`** from \vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\default.xml
2. And put it under `<body>`. The code should be looking **`<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true"></referenceContainer>`** in app\design\frontend\theme\theme-name\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml.